# How do you extract a specific element out of an XDocument?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I have the following XDocument:

```
<SomeDoc Id="73" Protocol="rahrah" xmlns="http://schemas.company.com/rah/rah2/2005/">
  <Prop1>11111</Prop1> 
  <Prop2>77777</Prop2> 
  <Prop3>88888</Prop3> 
</SomeDoc>
```

And I want to extract the value in Prop1.

I use the following code:

```
var prop1 = xml.Element("Prop1");
```

But prop1 is being set to null. Am I trying to extract the element correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that `xml` is the `XDocument` object itself.

An `XDocument` object contains the root element, not its children.  You need to write `xml.Root.Element("Prop1");`.

**EDIT**: You also need to include the namespace, like this:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.company.com/rah/rah2/2005/";
xml.Root.Element(ns + "Prop1");
```

Comment: Does the namespace need to be prefixed to the property name? I'm still only getting null returned.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks

var ns = xml.Root.Name.Namespace;

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the code that you are using to populate the xml variable?

My wild guess is that XDocument is not recognizing the xml fragment as a valid document. I think that XDocument is expecting the `<?xml version="1.0"?>` root node. You might need to use XmlTextReader instead of XDocument.

Comment: Wrong.  Otherwise, he would get an exception.